# Set or get html tags value or innerhtml in razor view

Tags: asp.net, razor

how to set or get html elements inner text or html controls value in Razor syntax.
i know how we can do this in aspx file using Runat="server" attribute like this

```css
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title><%Response.Write(Page.Title); %></title>
    <script runat="server">
        protected void Button1_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            p1.InnerText = "Hello " + textbox1.Value; //get textbox value and set in html p tag
        }
    
    
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="textbox1" runat="server" /><br />
            <input type="button" id="btn" runat="server" value="Click Me" onserverclick="Button1_ServerClick" />

            <p id="p1" runat="server">see result here</p>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically something like this...

View (SomeAction.cshtml):

```
...
<p>ViewBag.SomeValue</p>
...
```

Controller:

```
...
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
   ViewBag.SomeValue = "Hello";
   return View();
}
...
```

However you should learn much about approach which is used to build applications using ASP.MVC. It's completely different than ASP.NET WebForms. WebForms technology uses events while ASP.MVC uses Model View Controller. You have to change your mindset.